# Conditional page break on tablix

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a sub report with a tablix following it.

The subreport has conditional visibility, so it may be hidden, but I need it to be on a separate page from the tablix when it does appear.

I have tried adding a page break to the start of the tablix but this page break always appears.

Is there a way to make the page break conditional? I cannot see anywhere to add an expression to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much fiddling with settings and other options, I decided insert a rectangle between the sub report and tablix.

The rectangle has a millimetre height and is conditionally hidden along with the sub report.

The rectangle allows for a `PageBreak` property; so when it is visible there appears a pagebreak - as requirqd.

Sideways approach but it works.